# Interpreting padded string

Tags: python, unicode, nmap, html-escape-characters

I have little experience with unicode strings. I am not even sure this fits the criteria.

In any case I was using nmap and ran:

```
# nmap -sV -O 192.168.0.8
```

against a box in my LAN. Nmap produced a string over several lines returned from an open port, but I cannot understand a lot of the output due to its formatting. For example, a small snippet looks like this:

```
-Port8081-TCP:V=6.00%I=7%D=10/20%Time=52642C3A%P=i686-pc-linux-gnu%r(FourOhFourRequest,37,"HTTP/1\.1\x20503\x20Service\x20Unavailable\r\nContent-Length:\x200\r\n\r\n")%r
```

My first thought was URL encoding which requires decoding, but that's incorrect. It looks almost like padding from serial communication? Anybody able to shed light on how to interpret the "\x200" or "\x20503" or another that shows often is "x\20".

I thought about writing a small Python script to take in the entire string and convert to ASCII with:

```
>>> s = '<STRING>'
>>> eval('\x20"'+s.replace('"', r'"')+'"').encode('ascii')
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you see is a service fingerprint. It contains the responses that were received to the various probes that Nmap sends. If you think there is identifying information in the responses, please [submit the fingerprint](http://nmap.org/book/vscan-community.html) to the Nmap project to improve detection in the future.

More than likely, what happened is that the service is not sending any useful information. The sample you gave, for instance, does not have a `Server:` header that would identify the HTTP server.

To answer the technical problem of how to turn this string:

```
"HTTP/1\.1\x20503\x20Service\x20Unavailable\r\nContent-Length:\x200\r\n\r\n"
```

into an unescaped version, you can do this:

```
>>> print mystring
"HTTP/1\.1\x20503\x20Service\x20Unavailable\r\nContent-Length:\x200\r\n\r\n"
>>> print mystring.decode('string-escape')
"HTTP/1\.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Length: 0

"
```

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers bring to mind hexidecimal values due to the 'x' in front.
I know that hexidecimal values actually start with '0x' and not just x, but I thought it was worth googling them as hex values with the '0x' in front. I did get a full page of search results which seemed to contain these three values(perhaps inevitable that three random values would show up somewhere, but then again, perhaps not):

```
0x200, 0x20503, 0x20
```

Sorry that this isn't an answer as such, but I thought I would mention it since you didn't mention trying this in your post. I wanted to post this as a comment, but the option wasn't available for some reason...

Comment: I've looked further and it seems that the value is simply "\x20". In the "x20503" above, the 503 is the HTTP Error 503 (Service Unavailable). I think the "\x20" is escape character for space.